# How to remove paddings from heading tags in html?

Tags: html, css, padding, html-heading

I am trying to remove the top and bottom padding from the `<h1>` and `<h2>` tags. But as I've found out the `h1` and `h2` tags have inherent padding. I attempted to the use following CSS:

```
 h1,h2 { 
      padding: 0px; 
 }
```

However, that doesn't solve the problem. So how can I remove the padding from headings?

Answer (score 4):

The spacing around the header tags is actually controlled by margin, not padding. So you want to remove that instead. However, you can still set the padding to `0px` as well, just in case another selector actually sets that to a non-zero value

```
h1,h2 {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrxKjj) that shows it in action.